# Efficient way to set up roles and hierarchies using APEX

Tags: apex, administration, sharing, sharing-rule, criteria-based-sharing

I have this complex sharing structure where I have multiple levels of users and want to be able to dynamically assign/update sharing to records for different users. For example, let's say I have 20 Sales Reps and 5 "Zones". Each Account belongs to one zone. Each Sales Rep may have access to any number/combination of Zones so hard coding this all would be a nightmare, specially knowing that the number of Reps and Zones can grow.

I was hoping that I could build this using roles but I don't see a straightforward way to do this. I'm thinking of using Apex to dynamically create sharing rules and creating a UI so a user can say Rep 1 has access to Zone 1,3,4 and Rep 2 has access to Zone 1,2,3 and update them as needed. I'm thinking creating separate rules for each zone and including reps in them using Apex. Would this solution scale (i.e., hundreds of users, thousands of accounts with hundreds of thousands of detail records in tens of zones)? Any better approaches to tackle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have encountered this exact challenge before. The simplest approach I've found is to do the following:

- Create a Public Group for each Territory/Zone
- Assign users to their relevant Public Groups
- With either apex managed sharing or criteria based sharing create an AccountShare record with UserOrGroupId=Account Territory/Zone

The third bullet has a lot of very subtle benefits. You effectively share out all users with a single share record, which has obvious performance and maintainability benefits. You also can modify groups and thereby implicitly change sharing behavior.

Criteria based sharing is a little more brittle than apex managed sharing because you need a rule for each possible group assignment. The reason for this is you can't dynamically target a group in a sharing rule.

Answer (score 2):

[Territory Management](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=territories_def.htm&type=0) sounds like the feature you're looking for. Try this in a sandbox or developer edition first, of course. Roles are for a more traditional approach where a user has a defined place in an organizational hierarchy, and doesn't translate well to business processes that have overlapping territory.

Comment: Thanks! I did a quick read through. Seems like this is for standard objects and not managed custom objects. Almost all of our detail records belong to custom objects.
Also seems like Territory Management only works for accounts. How about custom objects?

Comment: @DavidJ If the records are controlled by the accounts (master-detail), it would still work, but if you need normal lookups managed by sharing, then you're right, this isn't the solution for you. Matthew McKinley's answer is an alternative I've implemented before using public groups and triggers, and we've scaled it to ~120 retail locations successfully across a few objects. It's certainly *possible* to do so if standard features don't meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks. Your solution will answer the majority of the cases but we do have one custom object that we would want to be able to use the sharing for. So I'll probably have to combine the two solutions.